# Trouble finding assets on my HTML, serving from a Go web server

Tags: javascript, html, go, server, filesystems

I am editing some tutorial code I found online, and wanted to add a front end. I got my router spitting out my html no problem, but the html cannot find my static files.
here is my main function

```
func main() {
   router := NewRouter()
   cssHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./css/"))
   imagesHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./images/"))
   scriptHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./scripts/"))

   http.Handle("/scripts/", http.StripPrefix("/scripts/", scriptHandler))
   http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", cssHandler))
   http.Handle("/images/", http.StripPrefix("/images/", imagesHandler))
   log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
```

}

here is my index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Go Do IT</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/toDoCtrl.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="toDoCtrl as ctrl">
      <div ng-repeat ="todo in ctrl.todos">
        {{todo}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

if you want to see all the code, here is a repo i am working on https://github.com/kekeoki/go-do-it
I have tried putting things in a grouped static folder, and most recently I moved the scripts folder to the base directory. If you have any good tutorial links, please let me know, everything I have found so far has not helped.
Thanks

Comment: I am getting Error : ./main.go:9: undefined: NewRouter Can you fix and push code so I can check!

Comment: I couldn't see your css and image folder?

Comment: @PravinMishra try go run *.go also I dont have the css or image up yet, just scripts, I figure if i can get scripts working I can get the rest working.

Comment: Please have a look to this code: https://github.com/diatmpravin/aakash/blob/master/main.go

Comment: @PravinMishra trying your code updated to look like this|

func serveResource(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
 print("serving")
 path := req.URL.Path
 print(req.URL.Path)
 http.ServeFile(w, req, path)
}
func main() {
 router := NewRouter()
 http.HandleFunc("/scripts/app.js", serveResource)
 http.HandleFunc("/scripts/todoCtrl.js", serveResource)
 log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}

however i never enter serve function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working, YOU MUST HAVE THE ./ IN FRONT OR IT WONT WORK.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func ServeStatic(router *mux.Router, staticDirectory string) {
    staticPaths := map[string]string{
        "styles":           staticDirectory + "/styles/",
        "bower_components": staticDirectory + "/bower_components/",
        "images":           staticDirectory + "/images/",
        "scripts":          staticDirectory + "/scripts/",
    }
    fmt.Println(staticPaths)

    for pathName, pathValue := range staticPaths {
        pathPrefix := "/" + pathName + "/"
        router.PathPrefix(pathPrefix).Handler(http.StripPrefix(pathPrefix,
            http.FileServer(http.Dir(pathValue))))
        fmt.Println(pathValue)
    }
}
func main() {
    router := NewRouter()

    staticDirectory := "./static"
    ServeStatic(router, staticDirectory)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

my scripts are in ./static/scripts/
I.E. ./static/scripts/app.js
TLDR treat each asset route as a route on your router, not a space on your file system

Comment: Better still: don't use relative paths. Have your application use absolute paths, be they simply passed via environmental variables or config file.

Comment: @elithrar good idea, will you give me an example? I am still pretty new to backend stuff with go.